# In Harry Potter, do witches and wizards use toilet paper, tampons, toothpaste, etc?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

So, I have been thinking of things people have to do regularly that (presumably) witches and wizards will also deal with.

- Do they use toilet paper after going to the toilet? There are bathrooms but I don't recall mention of toilet paper.
- Do they use tampons/pads? Presumably they still get their period.
- Do they brush their teeth, floss, or use toothpicks? I don't think there are any dentists (as I recall, wizards seem to be confused by Hermione's parents' occupation). So if they do, what is the point? What would happen if they didn't do these things?
- Do they use birth control? I'm assuming they wouldn't use pharmaceuticals...
- Do they have insurance? We need car insurance and health insurance and so on. Is there such a thing for witches and wizards? I would hope so...
- Do they get "regular" sick (Alzheimer's, Huntington's, AIDS/HIV, Cancer, Diabetes, Malaria)? I think there have been references to colds or the flu, but what about more serious non-magical ailments? Would St. Mungo's be able to cure cancer?

**EDIT**

I'll take the answer that in general we can only speculate, though some things I asked *are* covered or at least hinted at. Bonus points for the bit about the utensils x) I wasn't suggesting there's a "magical" solution for everything (though *wingardium leviosa* might do for eating no?)

Totally forgot about Hermione's teeth: [Why does the Weasleys' clock have a dentist setting?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60829/why-does-the-weasleys-clock-have-a-dentist-setting) Thanks to b_jonas for the link.

I guess this will do for toiletries and such (other than toothbrushes/toothpaste which are mentioned): [Nobody Poops (TV Tropes)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops). Thanks to calccrypto for that one.

Comment: I don't think canon covers any of it to be honest.

Comment: But toilet paper is a fairly recent Muggle invention so probably no :) In similar vein, things that are more recent Muggle stuff (insurance, floss) are unlikely

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: @DVK - Canon covers a few things, as do the films. But for the most part all the answers to all these questions is "Canon doesn't address this." :)

Comment: why wouldn't they use the same personal/hygiene products as the rest of the world?

Comment: @Deion: Because they teleport their poop directly from their digestive tracts to the sea, thus avoiding the need to construct sewerage systems. This is the origin of the long war between wizards and sanitation engineers.

Comment: How many books/movies have you seen that mention toilet paper?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that wizards would need to use tampons. Witches, are a different matter.

Comment: @Richard - to quote my favorite line from DayWatch novel (when they magically swapped the protagonist and his female friends into each others' bodies): "Like any modern man, I know perfectly well how to use the pads! You pour strange blue liquid on them, and then squeeze them in your hand to show that none leaks out!"

Comment: @DVK - Honeydukes sells something called "Toothflossing Stringmints", which Hermione says her parents (the dentists) would approve of. Do you think that would count as wizarding floss? The reference is in PoA.

Comment: Ha, he doesn't know about the shells.

Comment: @Slytherincess - yes.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, "Unless there's a magical version that's as good or better, I sure hope so."

Comment: Google translate is great for inventing HP-type spells: culus purgo, dentes purgo... I'll let someone else invent the tampon spell. FWIW, fanfiction has given us the birth control spell: contraceptus.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Harry wears glasses. Many wizarding characters in the series wear glasses. It's a stretch to suggest there is a magical implementation of every single thing in the world.

I see no reason why the wizarding world wouldn't partake of generic helpful items, Muggle or not, to care for their personal hygiene. A few examples from the movies:

- In the film *Goblet of Fire* as Ron is freaking out about his ugly dressrobes, Harry exits the bathroom holding a toothbrush.
- In the film *Half-Blood Prince*, Ron tells Hermione she has a bit of toothpaste on her face.
- In the films *Philosopher's Stone* and *Order of the Phoenix* Hagrid and Mr. Weasley take the tube (subway), respectively.
- In the film *Chamber of Secrets* "Dentist" is listed on the Weasley clock.
- In *Goblet of Fire*, the mere presence of the Prefect's Bathroom demonstrates wizards bathe normally, with soap and water.
- In *Chamber of Secrets*, Moaning Myrtle lives in a normal, Muggle toilet. Wizards go potty! I would assume they clean themselves appropriately, with toilet paper. The spell for cleaning is *Evanesco*; perhaps they use that in a pinch.
- They eat with utensils and don't use magic to get food from the plate to their mouths.

Just a few examples.

Tampons and pads are not addressed in canon. You forgot to mention the Diva Cup ;)

Birth control is not addressed in canon. I would imagine they do use birth control -- if they want to (Weasley family, I'm lookin' at you!) -- perhaps there are potions or charms to prevent pregnancy, or they use some form of the withdrawal method.

Insurance is not mentioned in canon, but for health care, as Britain has socialized medicine, I wouldn't expect wizards would carry individual health insurance coverage. Broom insurance and Bad Magic liability insurance is not mentioned.

I also believe colds and coughs have been mentioned in canon, but there are no instances of Alzheimer's or HIV being mentioned. *Could* they contract these conditions (okay, I realized one can't contract Alzheimer's, but hopefully it's clear what I mean)? Maybe Muggleborns or half-bloods could. I don't know about Purebloods. As for serioys magical maladies, in canon Horace Slughorn confirms that Draco Malfoy's grandfather died of Dragon Pox, so, yes, it's possible. Canon doesn't address cancer. But J.K. Rowling has always been clear that magic is not a cure-all. *Could* St. Mungo's cure cancer? We can only speculate.

Comment: To use an old quip, do you know what they call people who "use some form of the withdrawal method"? **PARENTS**.

Comment: Furthermore, in the film for the Chamber of Secrets, there is a sink for washing hands and the secret entrance to the Chamger is hidden inside/under it. (I don't remember if this is the case for the book). If they need to wash their hands after using the toilet, it must be presumed that the rest is the same.

Comment: @SylvainL Book. So is taking the train.

Comment: About the Weasley clock, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60829/4918

Comment: I was mainly wondering about serious NON magical maladies magical peoples might get, but I guess any half-blood can die of Huntington's just like they could die of dragon pox.

Comment: "Birth control is not addressed in canon... perhaps there are potions or charms to prevent pregnancy, or they use some form of the withdrawal method." and "The spell for cleaning is Evanesco; perhaps they use that in a pinch." in the same post, but it takes a comment to associate them...

Comment: Martyl's bathroom has a muggle flushing system, because at some point Harry monologues about imagining Martyl being flushed down with the contents of a toilet

Comment: I just want to point out that both toothbrush/toothpaste cases are with people who were raised Muggle and have brushed their teeth their whole life, so it makes sense that they would continue. We never hear about Ron brushing his teeth (although he does know what toothpaste is).

Comment: @b_jonas -- Re: the clock, yes, I've said the same thing practically verbatim at least twice in chat. It's a continuity error in the movies. :)

Comment: @Bobo - What you say makes sense. I kind of want to say that the *lack* of canon saying otherwise would suggest that wizards use the same basic hygiene tools/practices as Muggles. But not for everything. For example, Hermione uses Sleak-Easy Potion to do her hair before the Yule Ball. Maybe it's a combo of both. :)

Answer (score 5):

I imagine it would be pretty trivial for an adult wizard to use magic to clean up after pooping, but how would squibs do it? Also because of the Decree for the Reasonable Restriction of Underage Sorcery, children are not allowed to use magic when not at school so naturally there would be non magical ways of dealing with this. I assume that some sort of magical bidet would be very common in the homes of wealthier wizards though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for some reason, the students at Hogwart's don't use paper to write upon, but rather a form of leather. Parchment is a cured goat hide. While they do call the 
Daily Prophet a newsPAPER, there's no reason to assume it's really paper. The wizarding world doesn't seem to know what guns are, they don't know what ball point pens are, don't use family vehicles and in many other ways seem stuck in the year 1100 AD. I find it conceivable they use corn cobs or leaves or some other horribly harsh plant based product in the bathroom since they can't come to grips with the year in which they live.

Answer (score 0):

Wizards are portrayed as doing everything that they do regularly so why wouldn't they also do these things as well. It wasn't put into the books or movies, because this is a children's movie and also this is not important to the plot. But the wizards have bathrooms, so they are obviously doing something. And they bathe, so they are obviously getting dirty from regular human body functions.  They probably have magic get rid of the toilet paper and other items they use.

Comment: *Harry Potter* is for *all* ages, which is what makes it extra special. It's not just for children, movies or books.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Dumbledore uses Horace Slughorn's loo in Half-Blood Prince. (I do love knitting patterns).