# How is teen pregnancy handled at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Hogwarts is a school full of hormone-infused teenagers who spend a decent amount of time "snogging". It stands to reason that there is plenty of...extra-snoggular...activity going on.

***How is unwanted pregnancy handled/prevented at Hogwarts? Are there any examples of pregnancies occuring at Hogwarts or is there any evidence to support contraceptive spells?***

Comment: This would appear to be a dupe of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71277/58193) which itself is too broad so not sure of the best course of action though closing this probably makes the most sense.

Comment: Related:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/hogwarts-so-why-arent-the-kids-doing-it/61012#61012

Comment: I get that it might have been a dupe (the "related" from OP seems most likely), and the first three books may have been children's fare, but I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted quite so much.  It's not like JKR hasn't had huge blind spots, like the whole "love potion" thing...

Comment: I agree with @Radhil. The related I posted is targeted towards sex at Hogwarts. I am interested specifically in pregnancy. Also, reasons for down voting would be appreciated so I can improve the question.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/153734/931

Comment: "_reasons for down voting would be appreciated so I can improve the question"_ : You can't improve it, the question is the problem, you might as well ask "how do they deal with teenage pregnancy in Peter Rabbit?" they don't, it has no place in the Potterverse & is never dealt with in it, the simple answer is just "they don't", it's a silly question & people are telling you it's a silly question, some by commenting some just by voting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short it's not addressed and  (unless JKR has one too many glasses of wine when her Twitter account is open) will never *be* addressed.

> **Q. How overtly concerned are you with the idea of Harry's growing up in the books?**
>
> **JKR:** I do want him [Harry] to grow up. I want them all to grow up, but not in a way
> that's unfaithful to the tone of the books, i.e., **I feel it would be
> inappropriate-in these books -were Hermione to have an underage
> pregnancy or if one of them were to start taking drugs, because it's
> unfaithful to the tone of the books. It's not at all that I don't
> think those themes can be explored superbly in children's literature.
> It's just that in the Harry Potter books there isn't a place for those
> particular issues.** In book four, there is the most evidence so far
> that they're getting older, in that they start getting interested in
> boys and girls. Although there's been a hint of that in book three,
> this time it's out in the open.
>
> <sub><sup>Jones, Malcolm. "The Return of Harry Potter," Newsweek, 10 July, 2000</sup></sub>

These are books *for* children. You might as well ask how they're likely to address [ritual satanic child abuse](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/676446.Don_t_Make_Me_Go_Back_Mommy).

Comment: That interview question appears to have been asked when book 4 released. I wonder if the stance is the same for books 5, 6, and 7 which have MANY more adult themes.

Comment: @Newbie12345 - Given the lack of overt sex, rape, teen pregnancy, drug use, etc in the final three books, it's clear that this rule continued to apply

Comment: though - clearly the filmmakers in for Azkaban three thought there was some funny business happening in Hogwarts - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/hogwarts-so-why-arent-the-kids-doing-it/61012#61012

Comment: @NKCampbell - Apparently it was just a "peck on the cheek". And if you believe that, I've got a used Hippogriff I'd like you to consider buying.

Comment: Not to mention the possibilities and likelihood of pedophilia being an issue. Gilderoy Lockhart was capable of using his obliviation to steal others achievements and laud them as own. He was prepared to obliviate Harry and Ron in the Chamber of Secrets, what would he have done with say a seventh year female student after hours in say detention setting? The act of obliviation and his apparent mastery of the technique definitely leaves room for scenarios much darker than were ever explored without taking into account that these were children’s books until the latter three installments.

Comment: @Jacob - It sounds like you've read one slashfic too many.

Comment: No. I abhor slash. I simply say that his lack of moral compunction would not make him immune to other forms of idolization such as a student throwing herself at her teacher crush, especially given his specialty in obliviation easily covering up the evidence for him. If he can take credit for others achievements and build his career on them without being caught for many years, why would he care about accepting a pretty young girls affections, especially without the likelihood of being caught, a desire to feel flattered and receive attention and lack of moral fiber.

Comment: That formula is probably one of the most common scenarios for inappropriate student teacher relationships forming in real life. Abuse of authority and the ability to sweep it under the rug. Catholic priests have been doing it for centuries.

Answer (score 1):

Harry Potter has often shied away from issues like sex or drug abuse because in the end, it's set in a fairy tale world where years of emotional and sometimes physical abuse has not left Harry an insecure wreck.

It's an idealized world with well defined villans and heroes and very few moral grey areas. Therefore gritty realism and issues like Teen pregnancy etc. doesn't really have a place in Harry Potter series something the author herself agrees with:

> I feel it would be inappropriate-in these books -were Hermione to have an underage pregnancy or if one of them were to start taking drugs, because it's unfaithful to the tone of the books. It's not at all that I don't think those themes can be explored superbly in children's literature. It's just that in the Harry Potter books there isn't a place for those particular issues.

Now if one were to move away from JK Rowling's opinion on this issue, it would be rather easy to induce a abortion using muggle means.

In muggle means we have [Misoprostol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misoprostol) with up to 90% rate of abortion. The muggleborn students are sure to have heard of this drug and would use it in case it's required.

Magical means, I don't think exist since the population of magicals is so low, they would not bother developing effective contraceptive or abortion methods. Most pureblood families have one offspring, Weasleys being the exception. However its not unlikely for them to use muggle means like condoms/contraceptive pills for protection if they know about it.