# What is Hermione Granger's ethnicity?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

In all of the Potter books, there appears to be only one reference to Hermione's skin colour:

> *They were there, both of them, sitting outside Florean Fortescue’s Ice Cream Parlor — Ron looking incredibly freckly, **Hermione very brown**, both waving frantically at him.*
> <sub><sup>Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 4: The Leaky Cauldron</sup></sub>

While it would be easy to *assume* that JKR meant that she's tanned (e.g. from the sun), [other writers](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/black-harry-potter-characters-are-revolutionary_n_55aea1d5e4b0a9b94852c333?ri18n=true&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9jb25zZW50LnlhaG9vLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAFNkpAQesyj5GB48dNvliUEqE1cTqegFmEkN9Gy9Bxj_7A3OVs4y-wOMqceAWjttkg1DjZV-nWIyn9wvPE-AKsLh_D9pQ6aTqKxM8ADtFq1QWIJOEqbL3KgMufNh82fndgGiOoISfqPVHO7UEd6xjRrmBYggZp6ReIQvbNX1c3qf) have suggested that the line above, and [lack of other descriptors](http://www.blackgirldangerous.org/2013/12/radicalizing-fantasy-power-disidentification/) strongly implies that Hermione is naturally dark-skinned. Zeba Blay, the 'Voices Culture Writer' for Huffington Post even goes so far as to say that it's down to individual readers to make their *own judgement* on the issue.

> "So is the fictional character *actually* white? **Perhaps that's a determination readers should make for themselves.**" - <sub><sup>Italics and bolding mine</sup></sub>

---

**Is there any evidence either way? Has JKR ever given an in-universe reason to assume that Hermione is white, black or mixed-race?**

Comment: <Mod deleted comments> Comments are for clarification of the question. If you would like to debate race vs. ethnicity or the motivations for this question, do it in [chat].

Comment: It's a trope of British life that kids - especially well-off kids, which includes Hermione - spend some of their summer breaks outdoors and/or in sunnier climes than Britain, and therefore come back to school browner than when they left.

Comment: Sun promotes more freckles as well as tanned skin. It implies that they spent a lot of time outdoors.

Comment: @Richard Check out http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111437/what-ethnicity-skin-color-is-hermione-granger?lq=1

Comment: @randal'thor - Ooh, now that is interesting! That being said, I went to see a production of Othello a few years ago with a white Othello and a black Iago.

Comment: I dunno man. Imagine Rowling writing something like "Harry saw Tonks, Moody, and Kingsley Shacklebolt standing there, Shacklebolt looking very brown." Pretty weird, I think, when talking about an actual brown guy.

Comment: @Misha: JKR on Twitter, Dec, 21st: _"Canon: brown eyes, frizzy hair and very clever. White skin was never specified. Rowling loves black Hermione."_ https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/678888094339366914

Comment: @sbi - Prisoner of Azkaban - "*Hermione’s white face was sticking out from behind a tree."*. White skin *seems* to have been specified.

Comment: @Richard: That might well be. But the actual _author_ said, black skin would be just as good on Hermione. I'm not gonna dispute her on this.

Comment: @sbi - The major problem here (as I see it) is that JKR is disputing her own clear intention.

Comment: "JKR is disputing her own clear intention" - how did this get 13 upvotes? She didn't say that Hermione was meant to be brown or black, just that white skin was never specified *in the books*. And literally no one here found a single mention of her skin being specified as white. A brown person can be white-faced with fear just like a white person can be brown with tan (no one is literally white with fear anyway).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There are a few clues to Hermione's racial background;

### Hermione is described (in *Prison of Azkaban*) as having a 'white face'

> ‘One moment, please, Macnair,’ came Dumbledore’s voice. ‘You need to sign, too.’ The footsteps stopped. Harry heaved on the rope. Buckbeak snapped his beak and walked a little faster.
>
> **Hermione’s white face was sticking out from behind a tree.**
>
> ‘Harry, hurry!’ she mouthed.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - Chapter 21: "Hermione's Secret"</sup></sub>

Note, however that JKR has now gone [on record](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/2016/jun/05/jk-rowling-harry-potter-cursed-child-jack-thorne-john-tiffany-interview) as stating that this was not indicative of her race:

> “I had a bunch of racists telling me that because Hermione ‘turned white’ – that is, lost colour from her face after a shock – that she must be a white woman, which I have a great deal of difficulty with. But I decided not to get too agitated about it and simply state quite firmly that Hermione can be a black woman with my absolute blessing and enthusiasm.”

### Hermione is *drawn* Caucasian

The US versions of the *Harry Potter* books had [chapter illustrations](https://www.buzzfeed.com/keenan/every-harry-potter-chapter-illustration#.unldrVgVd) that were hand-chosen by JKR. Although it's a little hard to see the detailing, in the pictures that contain Hermione, she certainly appears to be white/Caucasian. There's no substantial shading and her colouration appears to be the same as Ron's and Harry's.

[image: Bust sketches of the main trio next to an open latter sketch with a logo coming out of it; all 3 look pale with Hermione perhaps the least so] [image: Sketch of the main trio stood together in their robes] [image: Sketch with Hermione performing a spell with her wand in front of an open book with Ron stood behind watching her]

### Hermione *is* JKR

In various [interviews](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc2.htm#p3), JKR has stated that Hermione is basically a [Mary Sue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue) character, essentially herself in fictional form:

> **Lydon:** *I was about to say 'are you Hermione?'*
>
> **JKR:** *Yeah - w-well - n-n-not ... I mean none of the characters in the books are directly taken from life. Real people did inspire a few of them, but of course once they are on the page they become something completely different. **But, yeah, Hermione is a caricature of what I was when I was 11** - a real exaggeration, I wasn't that clever - Hermione is a border-line genius at points - and I hope I wasn't that annoying, because I would have deserved strangling; sometimes she is an incredible know-it-all.*

It's by no means definitive, but it seems unlikely that someone portraying *themself* would change their race.

Comment: Do we know for certain that Rowling personally picked the illustrations?

Comment: @JasonBaker - There's a quote from her saying that she was very happy with them. I'll dig it up

Comment: @randal'thor - actually, [Hermione is @DVK](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18501/why-was-ron-so-nasty-to-hermione#comment34727_18501)

Comment: How do you know JKR isn't actually secretly black?

Comment: @Möoz - Because I've read her biography and seen pictures of her parents; http://aws-cf.ados.fr/prod/photos/4/0/7/1025407/430792/img-4307929c5.jpg?v=6

Comment: Those thumbnails are extremely small. Do you have better versions?

Comment: The points in your answer are relevant, I guess, but hardly give an answer, and I'd like to point out why: 1) a non-white person may be described as "white-faced" when afraid just like a white person may be described as "brown" after spending time in the sun (I can understand why you may think this is a little odd for a black person, but for someone who is Indian or from North Africa, this is 100% natural - no one is literally white-faced anyway), 2) the drawings are simply not canon and we don't know how much input she put into them,

Comment: and 3), she may be based on Rowling herself, but Rowling doesn't have brown frizzy hair and her parents aren't dentists, so that is hardly evidence she is white too.

Answer (score 182):

Stuff and nonsense. Why would you need to remark on Hermione's "very brown" skin if that was its normal shade? This is very clearly saying that both Ron and Hermione have been spending more time in the sun than they usually do; in Ron, it comes out as freckles, and in Hermione, it manifests as a tan.

Add in the book covers (by the time the later books, and especially the reissues, came out, JKR had enough clout to veto anything that was blatantly wrong) and the movie casting (for which we know JKR had input), and it's clear that people are trying to "read into" this one quote things that are definitely not there.

---

<sub>Word of God is now on record as saying Hermione's race was not specified, but in that case, the quote in question doesn't really make sense: unless we all acquire Mr. Data's observing capabilities, we wouldn't be able to tell whether Ms. Dumezweni spent her vacation deep underground in a cave vs. on a sunny beach. I think Ms. Rowling had a white girl in mind for Hermione while writing the books -- hence the allusions to turning pink, looking pale, and resembling a panda --, but she realizes that casting a play or movie is about more than physical descriptions. Remember that the original productions of Romeo & Juliet had a boy playing Juliet.</sub>

Comment: That may well be true, but nothing you've said amounts to actual evidence one way or another. As I said in my earlier comment, if she was mixed-race (for example) but normally quite fair-skinned, then it would be worthy of remark that she has become a darker shade in the sun.

Comment: "JKR had enough clout to veto anything that was blatantly wrong" or maybe JKR didn't care enough because hermione's skin color is ultimately inconsequential. the fact that something made it into the movie does not necessarily make it book-accurate, much less what JKR envisioned.

Comment: I think this is a good answer to a *different* question, and makes me wish that whatever that other question is had been asked instead.

Comment: This "answer" is nothing but a personal opinion. No effort to answer the actual question. (I think it's safe to say that most of us DO share this particular opinion. Nevertheless, the answer was exactly about how well founded this common opinion is. Repeating won't make it more true.)

Comment: @Richard But it's also worthy of remark if she were not mixed race. So the quote this question is founded on is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Agent_L: The question asks, essentially, "does this quote imply that Hermione is not white?", and the answer to that is a resounding "uh, no? what are you smoking and why aren't you sharing?". This isn't personal opinion; it's just how language and logic work. Saying that this quote implies anything about Hermione's race is about as logical as saying that it implies something about Ron's race.

Comment: @Martha No, Martha. The question is "**Has JKR ever given an in-universe reason to assume that Hermione is white, black or mixed-race?**". And you gave absolutely nothing on this topic. I do understand your "Nonsense!" reaction (mine was same), but it's not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Martha I edited a bit to make your meaning more clear; feel free to rollback/edit more if needed

Comment: @Daenyth: Hermione doesn't have a shade, her skin does.

Comment: Why would you need to remark on her "bushy brown hair" if that was its normal appearance?  Because it's a book, and how else are we supposed to know what the characters look like?  The question does not assume one thing or another, simply asks what canon evidence there is of her race.  I am not sure how you got so many upvotes with a non-answer, but such is life, I suppose.

Comment: I think "what was Noma Dumezweni doing so far underground?" is an excellent follow-on question to this :-)

Comment: I find it very amusing that you think only white people can get browner.

Comment: Moreover, it is obvious that many actors in the films don't look exactly like their characters. For crying out loud, Harry has blue eyes in the films. *It just doesn't matter*. If Harry's eye color, which has been discussed countless of times in the books, was not important in Rowling's eyes, *of course* Hermione's skin color (which was practically never discussed in the books) is inconsequential.

Answer (score 148):

Although not exactly evidence, Rowling has done occasional sketches of her characters, all of which portray Hermione as having light skin:

- In 1999, she did [a sketch of her main characters](https://alltop.com/viral/harry-potter-characters-drawn-by-jk-rowling-i), but I don't know the story behind it:

  [image: A sketch of Hagrid, Snape, Dumbledore, McGonagall, Ron, Harry, Hermione, the Sorting Hat and Dobby all stood together; a close up shows the Hermione sketch: long bushy hair and pale skin]
- She released a sketch of a scene from *Philosopher's Stone* on her website in 2004 ([archived by the HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/other-canon/jkr/jkr-com-scrapbook/)):

  [image: A sketch of the main trio with Dean and presumably Neville moving through the dark with candles; Hermione is depicted as in the previous drawing]

  The fifth character, on the far right, is presumably an early version of the character who would become Dean Thomas; [Pottermore reveals](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty) that a character named "Gary Thomas" was one of the Original Forty Hogwarts students created by Rowling, later renamed "Dean." Since we know that Dean is dark-skinned, and he appears dark(er)-skinned in the sketch, it stands to reason that Hermione was intended to be light-skinned<sup>1</sup>.

Unfortunately, none of this tells us if she was meant to be mixed-race or not.

Obviously I'm reaching a bit here, and how canonical these drawings are is a matter of personal taste. Nevertheless, it gives some insight into Rowling's mind when she created the character, and I've found no evidence to suggest she changed it.

It's also potentially worth pointing out that there are abundant examples of Hermione being described as "looking pale" throughout the books. Again, though, this isn't evidence of much; the examples are always in high-stress situations, and a pale complexion in those sorts of situations has little-to-nothing to do with skin colour.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hat-tip to Jason (no relation) in comments for nudging me in this direction

Comment: I think the illustration shows enough talent that we would be able to tell if Hermione was intended to be completely non-white, although perhaps it doesn't completely rule out some sort of ethnic mix.

Comment: What the hell is that thing in the lower left hand corner?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Though, her hair not very brown in this sketch either, though it is clearly stated several times in the first book that she has brown hair.

Comment: @WadCheber Dobby, of course

Comment: What surprises me is how visible Snape's 5 o'clock shadow is in that first illustration, when I never pictured him with stubble at all.

Comment: Because an early version of a black character stayed black,  Rowling can't have changed her mind about Hermione since making this sketch? That sounds like a non sequitur to me.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but in the sketches, Hermione looks geeky, with rabbit teeth. Quite different from the cute little Emma Watson http://news.makemeheal.com/images/emma-watson-young.jpg

Comment: @Junuxx I don't think his point was that Hermione didn't change because the other character didn't, but rather that Rowling _did_ clearly draw the other character in such a way that their darker complexion was obvious. This implies that, had she intended other characters in the scene to have dark skin, she would have done the same for them. The answer does not say that Rowling _could not have_ later changed her mind about Hermione's complexion, only that there's no evidence she did so.

Comment: @Nav: In the books, Hermione did have too big front teeth, until *Goblet of Fire* where she got them magically shrinked, see quotes from http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60839/4918 .

Comment: Congrats on 3rd gr8 answer

Comment: Gary being an early version of Dean was stated in the text that accompanied the orignal picture on Rowling's site. It wasn't new to Pottermore.

Comment: These are interesting drawings (so I upvoted) but they don't really answer the question, which was whether JKR has given an "in-universe" reason to assume Hermione's ethnicity. The answer to that remain "no".

Comment: And as a (humorous) side note: maybe she first drew Dean, realized she doesn't know how to draw dark-skinned people and just made him look like a zombie, and decided to stop coloring people in. When you have white paper, it is easiest to draw white people

Answer (score 80):

Hermione is repeatedly described in the books as having *bushy brown hair*.

Naturally dark skin typically goes with dark or downright black hair. Now while *brown*, of course, can range through a variety of shades, some of them quite dark, I think we can rely on Rowling's eloquence (so manifest on other occasions) to believe that, had she meant *dark* (or black) hair, she would have said so. For me at least, when hearing *brown*, the expectation is chestnut, not coffee.

Also, Hermione is in the habit of turning pink rather often.

> "I love you, Hermione," said Ron, sinking back in his chair, rubbing his eyes wearily. Hermione turned faintly pink, but merely said, "Don't let Lavender hear you saying that."

[HBP, ch.20]

Oh well. A *brown*-haired girl who's in the habit of turning *pink*.

Comment: This charming young lady is literally the first person who comes up when I search on google for "[Bushy hair](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/34/61/0d/34610de9414c3922a9f8802d91e4fdb2.jpg)"

Comment: @Richard Quite. Her hair is naturally dark and (presumably) curly. Credit the hairdresser for the highlights and lots of the bushiness.

Comment: You have my +1 for her turning faintly pink. That's conceivable for a mixed-race complexion, but highly unlikely.

Comment: @Richard - As anemone said, that woman's hair would be black, not brown, if not for the hair dye. At the start of the series Hermione is a nerdy little girl who doesn't seem like the type to be using beauty products like dye or makeup at that age, so I think brown must be her natural hair color--and as far as I know, naturally brown hair is only seen in people with European ancestry (though again this doesn't totally rule out some kind of mixed heritage).

Comment: @Hypnosifl North-African people can have brown hair too. Try searching for Berber or Moroccan. Arguably, this can be from blood mixing from the Iberian invaders... but don't forget the strong counter-argument that Iberians have darker complexions due to blood mixing with Moorish people.

Comment: @Richard Now try googling [bushy brown hair](https://www.google.com/search?q=bushy+brown+hair&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  I find it kind of amazing that half the pictures are of Emma Watson as Hermione.

Comment: @ANeves Both of those arguments are true. Iberian invaders, primarily Germanic Vandal tribes in the early 400's came into North Africa and mixed with tribes in Numidia and former Carthage. Then, in the early 700's, the Umayyad Caliphate invaded North Africa and Iberia and established the Emirate of Cordova. So the mixing went back and forth, they're not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Bushy brown hair... It's no proof either way, but I've been told there's a stereotype of difficult or unmanageable hair linked to certain ethnicities.  I would believe a darker brown just fine, but I don't think she specifies, that's only opinion.  A lighter complexion shows her skin pinks, as you spotted, but a tan one shows when she pales (several times, in fright), and it would be emphasized (as the quote) when she browns.  I don't see anything that would contradict a mixed ethnicity, as long as she tended to the lighter end of the spectrum - light to mid tan, with bushy brown hair.

Answer (score 58):

This is a panda:

[image: A panda sat on its backside looking at the camera]

This is a panda's description

> The giant panda has a body shape typical of bears. It has black fur on its ears, eye patches, muzzle, legs, arms and shoulders. The rest of the animal's coat is white.

What did we learn? Pandas have white fur on their faces, and black fur around their eyes.

Here is a quote about Hermione from *Half-Blood Prince*.

> Hermione emerged, coughing, out of the smoke, clutching the telescope and sporting a brilliantly purple black eye.

Here is a second quote moments later when Mrs. Weasley attempts to fix Hermione's eye.

> Hermione sitting at the kitchen table in great agitation, while Mrs. Weasley tried to lessen her resemblance to half a panda.

Let's summarize

1. Pandas have white faces.
2. Pandas have black fur around their eyes.
3. Hermione has a black eye.
4. Hermione looks like half a panda.

Moral of the story, Hermione is **white**... or a **panda**.

[panda link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda#Description)

Comment: This is some excellent sleuthing. And yes, that is indeed a panda. The picture was most instructive.

Comment: @Richard i felt that for some users benefit we must show what a panda looks like. :D

Comment: Your conclusion, while not only incorrect, conflates morals with summaries, a most errant decision.

Comment: til moral = "a lesson, especially one concerning what is right or prudent, that can be derived from a story, a piece of information, or an experience."

Comment: I'm now tempted to ask if there's any canon confirmation that Hermione isn't a panda.

Comment: But what if she's a [Quinling panda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qinling_panda)?! They're brown.

Comment: @Himarm I nearly died laughing, this is the best response I've ever read.

Answer (score 44):

Very brown is a British term for looking tanned after outdoor sports or a holiday. Ron looking "incredibly freckly" would mean as a redhead, he's very pale and doesn't tan at all.

Examples would be in real life, and I recall Enid Blyton's boarding school books referring to a sporty character looking brown after the summer hols.

> 'Hallo, Sally! How brown you are!'
>
> Mary-Lou was at the deep end, watching the others. At least, she watched Darrell mostly, admiring the way she swam, cutting the water so cleanly with her strong brown arms, and thrusting through the waves like a small torpedo.
>
> A pair of wicked eyes looked out of the window of a car, and a tuft of hair fell over a brown forehead. 'I may have!' said Betty, stepping out.
>
> [*Mallory Towers* series](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZ_3AQAAQBAJ&q=brown#v=snippet&q=brown&f=false) by [Enid Blyton](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=usknAwAAQBAJ&q=brown#v=snippet&q=brown&f=false)

Comment: Can you offer a quote?

Comment: The weather had been so very hot lately. Day after day had brought nothing but blue sky and sunshine. George had been burnt a dark-brown, and her eyes were startlingly blue in her sunburnt face...George, how brown you are! http://www.amazon.com/Five-Away-Together-Famous-Book-ebook/dp/B007JNX5ZI

Comment: @Fillet thanks and I have added quotes of my own too.

Comment: Can you offer any confirmation that JKR has read Enid Blyton or that she has used the expression in any of her other writings?

Comment: @Richard - I think riddler was just using Enid Blyton as an example of an author using a reasonably common turn of phrase, not saying she coined this description of a suntan. If you search on google books for "browned by the sun" or "sun browned", you find plenty of other examples, for example p. 252 of *The Sun Also Rises* by Ernest Hemingway says "They drank much wine and were all burned and browned by the sun". Also see the entry for "brown" in [this Learners' Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=AB1f965CUnwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA80) with the example "you'll brown nicely in the sun today".

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed that entry in the Learners' Dictionary gives a usage example even closer to JKR's--"suntanned: *She was very brown after her holiday in Greece.*"

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Don't get me wrong. I think this is a good answer. Offering a quote that suggests that JKR has used the phrase elsewhere or read an author who's used that phrase would turn this from a good answer into a great answer.

Comment: Yes, as @Hypnosifl said, it's a British colloquial term. It doesn't necessarily mean that JKR read this phrase in Enid Blyton's books."Jo maintained her thirst for reading during this period as well, picking up books by such authors as Edith Nesbit, Enid Blyton, and series such as What Katy Did by Susan Coolidge and C.S. Lewis's well-known Chronicles of Narnia." Unofficial biography based on interviews https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GJgbW9c9mpwC&q=enid+blyton#v=snippet&q=enid%20blyton&f=false and another source http://www.hp-lexicon.org/muggle/encyc/muggle-b.html#blyton_enid

Answer (score 36):

I was having a discussion with a friend about this question, and he said something along the lines of this:

> I too assumed that Hermione was white because of my prejudices.

I disagree: it's not prejudice that makes my friend think Hermione is white. Instead, I think my friend picked up on a number of subtle clues embedded into the text of *Harry Potter*. Rightly or wrongly, Western culture and the English language use a number of vague and unusual techniques to convey information about race. This is why, while JKR never explicitly states the race of many of her characters, we can infer the race of many of these characters by taking a close look at the language, or rather the lack of language, that she uses to describe these characters.

I previously claimed that JKR only specifies the race of non-white characters. I've done further research, and I know that is not true. I've found a number of examples where JKR does discuss the skin color of *white* characters. (I'll get to those examples in a second). However, I still stand by the following idea, which is going to inform the rest of my answer:

> I think it is possible that some readers never even notice what color the people in the story are. Don't notice, don't care. Whites of course have the privilege of not caring, of being "colorblind." Nobody else does.
>
> ([Slate, A Whitewashed Earthsea](https://slate.com/culture/2004/12/ursula-k-le-guin-on-the-tv-earthsea.html))

Here's the claim that I'm going to spend the rest of my answer proving. JKR will specify the skin color of her characters only in a few specific circumstances:

1. If a character is a minority. This is because for most (almost all) minorities, skin color is an important part of their identity **because it's the feature that the rest of society judges them by**.
2. If a character is evil. One of the defining features of Voldemort is that he is deathly (almost unnaturally) pale. Many other characters who are (initially) associated with evil are also described in similar ways.
3. If there is a "biological reason" for describing a characters skin color, e.g. if a character is sick, scared, depressed, or (as quoted in the question) tanned from the sun. For example, when Tonks is depressed in *The Half-Blood Prince*, she is described as "pale". I would suspect that this is because being pale is a symptom of being sick.

**In all other cases, when JKR does not describe the skin color of a character, it is because that character is white**. Minorities in Western cultures do not have the privilege of ignoring their skin color; whites can go through their entire lives without thinking about the fact that they are white. This is because if you are white, you won't be systematically discriminated against because of the color of your skin; everyone else will be.

I can prove this by the fact that I only found one instance where a character was described as white, and none of the above reasons applied (see the bottom answer for a discussion about that). But I think it should also make sense that white characters don't think about or notice the fact that they are white. In fact, it's even awkward for people to say things like "my white friend" or "I'm white", even if those sentences are true.

> In Learning To Be White: Money, Race and God in America, the theologian and college professor Thandeka describes an little social experiment she devised called The Race Game.   The origins of this game were this: At a lunch together, a white member of the staff at Smith College asked Thandeka what it felt like to be black.  Thandeka said that if her luncheon partner played The Race Game for one week, she would then answer the colleague’s question.  The game consisted of one rule.  For one week the woman was to “use the ascriptive term white” whenever she mentioned the names of “Euro-American cohorts.   She must say, for instance, ‘my white husband, Phil,’ or ‘my white friend Julie,’ or ‘my lovely white child Jackie.’”  The women never had lunch with Thandeka again.  Over and over, when Thandeka presented the idea of The Race Game, white colleagues refused to do it.  Thandeka remarks: “…in their [my white colleagues’] racial lexicon, their own racial group becomes the great unsaid.”
>
> ([Notes on Questioning Whiteness as a Literary Practice](http://gulfcoastmag.org/online/blog/whiteness-as-literary-practice/))

So for a number of reasons, both the fact that white characters don't need to think about their race and the fact that it's uncomfortable for white characters to think about their race, it makes sense that Hermione wouldn't be described as white, at least in the same way that other minority characters are described as black.

---

In researching this answer, I literally searched through every book looking for references to characters skin color. I'm not going to include every quote I find because this answer would be too long. I also found one exception, which I've included at the bottom of the answer. Here are the results:

#### Minority Characters

> "Thomas, Dean," a Black boy even taller than Ron, joined Harry at the Gryffindor table.
>
> (*Sorcerer's Stone*)

> 'Yeah, I see what you mean, Remus,' said a bald black wizard standing furthest back - he had a deep, slow voice and wore a single gold hoop in his ear - 'he looks exactly like James.'
>
> (*Order of the Phoenix*)

#### "Evil" Characters

> [Voldemort] was standing in a dark, curtained room lit by a single branch of candles. His hands were clenched on the back of a chair in front of him. They were long-fingered and white as though they had not seen sunlight for years and looked like large, pale spiders against the dark velvet of the chair.
>
> (*Order of the Phoenix*)

> Harry twisted around, his own wand held high, and saw that the Death Eater had ripped off his mask and was pointing his wand directly at Harry, who recognised the long, pale, twisted face from the Daily Prophet: Antonin Dolohov, the wizard who had murdered the Prewetts.
>
> (*Order of the Phoenix*)

> And he threw the copy of The Quibbler to her. She caught it and stared down at the cover. Her pale, doughy face turned an ugly, patchy violet.
>
> 'When did you do this?' she asked, her voice trembling slightly.
>
> 'Last Hogsmeade weekend,' said Harry.
>
> She looked up at him, incandescent with rage, the magazine shaking in her stubby fingers.
>
> (*Order of the Phoenix*)

> And from behind the six large figures before them came a seventh, smaller boy, smirking all over his pale, pointed face. It was Draco Malfoy.
>
> (*Chamber of Secrets*)

#### Sick/Depressed/Scared Characters

> A young witch with a pale, heart-shaped face and mousy brown hair was sitting at the table clutching a large mug between her hands.
>
> "Hello, Professor," she said. " Wotcher, Harry."
>
> "Hi, Tonks."
>
> <sub>(This is in *The Half-Blood Prince*, when Tonks is feeling depressed because of Lupin. When they get engaged, Tonks is no longer described as Pale.)</sub>

> 'Harry, dear, are you sure you're all right?' said Mrs Weasley in a worried voice, as they walked around the unkempt patch of grass in the middle of Grimmauld Place. 'You look ever so pale . . . are you sure you slept this morning? You go upstairs to bed right now and you can have a couple of hours of sleep before dinner, all right?'
>
> (*Order of the Phoenix*)

#### Exceptions to my theory

> "Well, well, well," said the Fat Lady, "Violet's just told me everything. Who's just been chosen as school champion, then?"
>
> "Balderdash," said Harry dully.
>
> "It most certainly isn't!" said the pale witch indignantly.
>
> "No, no, Vi, it's the password," said the Fat Lady soothingly, and she swung forward on her hinges to let Harry into the common room.
>
> (*Goblet of Fire*)

I'm not quite sure about this quote: if anyone has any ideas, let me know in the comments. I suspect this is because Violet is associated with alchohol (she drinks a lot with the Fat Lady), and her being described as pale might be because of that. However, I'm not 100% sure about that argument.

Comment: Note that language tends to be economic

Comment: That unspoken rule is incomplete. The assumption is "all characters are the nationality of the country the literature is set in, unless specified otherwise."

Comment: @Scott That's not true; please see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 24):

The non-US *Deathly Hallows* cover depicts her as light skinned, as does the "new" Scholastic cover, so one can easily assume that the quote in question is indeed indicating a tan.

[image: Both the covers described above left-to-right: Tha main trio dive through a pile of treasure; the main trio sit on the back of a pale dragon]

Also, Jim Kay has done the illustrations for the new editions.  The one of Hermione is featured on Pottermore, and Jim Kay's illustrations have received [JKR's stamp of approval](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/books/what-to-read/harry-potter-illustrated-jim-kay/).  At a minimum, then, we can assume that the last illustration is correct, and she is at least of white skin color, though we cannot definitely rule out mixed race.

[image: Hermione in her robes pointing her wand at a lamp]

Comment: Can you give an indication that those covers were chosen by JKR herself?

Comment: The cover of my copy of PoA also features a light-skinned Hermione (riding on Buckbeak with Harry).

Comment: @Richard Thanks to another question, I linked a Telegraph article wherein JKR is quoted as approving of Jim Kay's illustrations.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105522/are-the-illustrations-in-harry-potter-and-the-philosophers-stone-illustrated-ed

Comment: I have never like the front cover of the Bloomsbury (non-adult) edition of _Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows_ — those flushed faces seem to come from a different world, though I suppose it makes sense in context.

Answer (score 21):

**According to JK Rowling, Hermione’s ethnicity is not definitively stated in canon.**

Quoting her on Twitter:

> > *@mauvedust: like. especially rowling. how does she feel about black hermione. i need to know.*
>
> Canon: brown eyes, frizzy hair and very clever. White skin was never specified. Rowling loves black Hermione
>
> — [@JK_Rowling on Twitter, 21 December 2015](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/678888094339366914)

This follows the announcement that Noma Dumezweni has just been [cast as Hermione](https://www.pottermore.com/news/cursed-child-play-casts-harry-hermione-and-ron) in the stage play *The Cursed Child*.

Just because she didn’t explicitly specify an ethnicity doesn’t mean she didn’t have one in mind. She’s made comparisons between Hermione and herself at a young age. I think it’s likely she had a white Hermione in mind when she wrote the books, which might explain some of the wording choices – but was careful never to pin it down entirely.

Comment: Welp, that's a word of God answer if I ever saw one. +1

Comment: I saw the post on BBC News and came to check, and as I expected it was already posted.

Comment: I've tweeted at her to question the line from POA where she talks about Hermione's white face. Maybe she'll answer, maybe she won't :-)

Comment: Although I'm minded to change my acceptance, I'm going to hold fire until there's a word-of-god explanation of the line mentioned in my answer. In the meantime you can have an upvote.

Comment: Set Retcon Shields to "Lucas", Mr Sulu.

Answer (score 10):

I just got the new illustrated version of *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* (US Edition), and Hermione appears to be Caucasian:

[image: Hermione in her school uniform and robes pointing her wand at a jar to light it up presumably with Lumos]

Here's the new book:

[image: Book cover showing the Hogwarts Express steaming along the track with Hedwig flying to its side above Harry who stands with other students amongst the luggage]

Comment: And this one; http://i.stack.imgur.com/ghJE5.png

Comment: And this one; http://i.stack.imgur.com/C0zpf.png

Comment: Also see [DaveJohnson's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105468/19561) which uses the same image.

Answer (score 9):

1. Mixed race people do not always have dark or black hair
2. JKR herself said in an interview that Emma Watson looked just like Hermione, only more beautiful. I think that's pretty definitive. Also, wouldn't she have mentioned it at some point if people were wrong?

Comment: Can you link to that interview?

Comment: I'm not sure the relevance of point 1

Comment: Maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/2xlxn6/til_jk_rowling_agrees_that_emma_watson_was_too/?

Comment: @user165604 - She doesn't actually say that though, what she says is that she's (verbally) like she always imagined her, but not physically.

Comment: I'm not sure what point 2 has to do with it either. Of course she doesn't look "just like" Emma Watson. What she means is that she is very similar to her. It is your opinion that white people can't look similar to non-white people.

Answer (score 9):

Considering her name, the fact that the only place where she is referred to as brown is when she returned from a place that is sunnier than usual, and the fact that she lives in Britain, and thus the default assumption would be Anglo-Saxon, I would say by far the most likely answer is that it referred to a tan.

Wikipedia's list of people named Hermione contains 9 people described variously as English or British, and 1 (from 110 AD) who lived in Rome, and whose father was white.

Of those 9, 6 have pictures on the Wikipedia article and are white, 1 has a link to IMDb with pictures showing they are white. The others are a Baroness and a President at Oxford college. I'm going to go out on a limb and assume they are white too.

In fiction, Hermione's are generally British/English, with a smattering of Italians and one person from Ancient Greek Mythology.

Turning now to Granger, there are too many people on Wikipedia for me to go through 1 by 1, but they are predominantly British/English, the American 2nd most common (of the 5 I clicked on, 4 were white and one was Native American), or French/Australian/New Zealander/Canadian (I clicked on 5 that were all white). There are, however, 1 each from Guyana, Trinidad/Tobago, and the Caribbean.

Looking at fiction, then every character with the last name of Granger listed in Wikipedia is white, with one exception, of a character in the anime *Beyblade*, where the character has a Japanese name in the Japanese version, and a 'Western' name with surname Granger for the English translation.

So in reality, a person named Hermione Granger is most likely white, but in fiction, the probability of someone named Hermione Granger not being white becomes vanishingly small.

Answer (score 9):

From Chapter 8 - "The Quidditch World Cup" of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*:

> Mr. Malfoy's eyes had returned to Hermione, who **went slightly pink**, but stared determinedly back at him.

Skins high on melanin don't go pink. She was brown (in quote of your question) because of high UV ray exposure issue or other health issue.

Answer (score 8):

Concerning your specific quote, I'd say she just had a nice tan as she had just come back from a holiday in France:

> Dear Harry,
>
> Ron wrote to me and told me about his phone call to your Uncle Vernon. I do hope you’re all right.
>
> I’m on holiday in France at the moment and I didn’t know how I was going to send this to you – what if they’d opened it at Customs? – but then Hedwig turned up! [...]
>
> *(The Prisoner of Azkaban)*

In *The Order of the Phoenix*, Hermione says to Hagrid she's been to [Dijon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijon) on a holiday:

> I was headin' fer where Olympes school is, 'cause we knew we was bein' tailed by someone from the Ministry. We had to go slow, 'cause I'm not really's'posed ter use magic an' we knew the Ministry'd be lookin' fer a reason ter run us in. But we managed ter give the berk tailin' us the slip round abou' Dee-John —'
>
> 'Ooooh, Dijon?' said Hermione excitedly. 'I've been there on holiday, did you see -?'
>
> *(The Order of the Phoenix)*

While Dijon is not [particularly warm or sunny](http://www.weather.gov.hk/wxinfo/climat/world/eng/europe/fr_sw/dijon_e.htm) during the summer, you're only a few hours from lots of beaches on the south coast of France.

Comment: But is she a Caucasian with a nice tan or another race/ethnicity?

Comment: @Richard I was merely commenting on the quote, and I agree with most of the answers you've got. I'd also add that Rowling has never been very strong on physical descriptions. It was never mentioned, for example, that Dean Thomas was black, and although Cho Chang and the Patil twins have typical Chinese/Korean and Indian surnames, their appearance is never explicitly described.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a picture of the 3 people that will be playing Harry, Hermione and Ron in the stage play *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*.

[image: The actors who will be playing the main trio in TCC; two white men and a black woman]
<sup>The people who will be playing Harry, Hermione and Ron in *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*.</sup>

The woman playing Hermione is actress [Noma Dumezweni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noma_Dumezweni). She was born in Swaziland to South African parents, before moving to England as a child.

This casting announcement has been [confirmed by Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/cursed-child-play-casts-harry-hermione-and-ron), in which J K Rowling states;

> "I’m so excited with the choice of casting for *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*. I can’t wait to see Jamie, Noma and Paul bring the adult Harry, Hermione and Ron to life on stage next summer."

Thanks to the fact that there is nothing in the text of the books (by which I mean a definitive mention of Hermione's race) to support a hypothesis either way, we can conclude that;

- In the films, Hermione is canonically white, having been played by actress [Emma Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Watson).
- In the stage play, she is canonically black, being played by actress [Noma Dumezweni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noma_Dumezweni).
- In the books, J K Rowling does not specify a skin colour for Hermione that cannot be interpreted as a demonstration of emotion. Her delight at both Emma Watson and Noma Dumezweni playing Hermione would seem to indicate that she simply doesn't care about this aspect of Hermione's character.

Comment: In the books she **does** specify a skin colour for Hermione, as I pointed out in [my own answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105487/20774); "***Hermione’s white face** was sticking out from behind a tree.*"

Comment: @Richard Arguably, given the context of the quote, Hermione is scared/faint/nervous, not Caucasian.

Comment: Regardless of the context, I find it unbelievable that a children's author would describe a black character as being white-faced with fear. That's just a great big 'no-no'.

Comment: @Richard Well, I made sure to specify that I was talking about the text of the books, not potential subtext or out-of-universe interpretation of author intention. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: Actually, JKR even gave a comment to this on Twitter: _"Canon: brown eyes, frizzy hair and very clever. White skin was never specified. Rowling loves black Hermione."_ https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/678888094339366914. Here, have an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

In the junior novelization of *Harry Potter & the Goblet of Fire*, Hermione's mother is described as having green eyes and pale skin. This provides fair evidence that Hermione is at least half-Caucasian.

Comment: I'll try to get a direct quote later tonight when I am able, but Reddit has discussed this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SubredditDrama/comments/2t8gye/how_can_we_tell_that_hermoine_granger_is_white/).

Comment: I'm struggling to pin down a quote. According to the wiki, her eye colour is confirmed in the films only  - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger%27s_mother#cite_note-DHPO-0

Comment: I don’t think her parents’ appearance is described in the books. We meet them in _Chamber of Secrets_ (_At Flourish and Blotts_), but there is nothing about what they look like.

Comment: @chirlu - Agreed. I think the Reddit writer is getting mixed up between the film and the book

Comment: @Richard possible. i'm still searching, but multiple people are making similar claims.

Comment: @phantom42 - Since this doesn't tally with what's in the books, I was wondering if you'd want to delete this answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, I downvoted the answer because the films (let alone their novelizations) are clearly not (book-)canon.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the early official covers of *Harry Potter: Prisoner of Azkaban* book:

[image: Harry Potter Prisoner of Azkaban cover] [image]

The girl behind Harry on Buckbeck is definitely Hermione as per story. You can clearly see that she is white.

Comment: Authors famously have [very little control over their book covers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26403/does-harry-dresden-of-the-dresden-files-book-series-wear-a-hat).

Answer (score 0):

As other users have provided plenty of evidence for the ethnicity/race of Hermione, I want to talk about the snippet that prompted this question and explain a different interpretation.

I think a more accurate interpretation of this snippet would be that this is a description of the most prominent feature. For Ron, his most prominent feature is the Weasley freckled skin and red hair. For Hermione, that is her ample bush of brown hair on her head. So for Ron, he's labeled by the freckles on his skin, while Hermione is labeled by her brown hair.

And yes, Weasleys are known for their freckles, as mentioned by Draco Malfoy in Philosopher's stone (not sure what chapter, if anyone knows, feel free to edit):

> No need to ask who you are. My father told me all the Weasleys have red hair, freckles and more children than they can afford.

Comment: This make sense except that she didn't identify Blaine Zabini's race until book 4

Comment: @richard and this is relevant to the snippet in what way? I do not even know who Zabini is due to reading the book in Dutch.

Comment: Blaine Zabini is a character who appeared in the first book as one of Harry's fellow students. It wasn't revealed until the fourth book that he was black. That would seem to contradict your assertion that JKR always speaks about the character's most prominent feature.

Comment: @Richard I'm sorry, but Blaine Zabini is about as minor a character as you can get. In the books, he literally has one noteworthy scene, in the Slug Club onboard the Express in HBP. The only reason he got a bigger role in the movies was because the actor playing Crabbe got community service when they shot the FyendFyre scenes in DHP2 and they needed another Slytherin to support Malfoy and Goyle.

Answer (score -2):

> Has JKR ever given an in-universe reason to assume that Hermione is white, black or mixed-race?

## **No.**

There are many answers here but most of them, in my eyes, do not answer the question, and I feel there should be a definite, no-nonsense answer here.

Let me mention a few things that should be obvious:

1. The films are *obviously* not canon. They differ from the books in countless places.
2. The illustrations are not canon. I have no idea why anyone would think they are.
3. Non-white people become tanned just like everybody else. Certainly people who are not black may become more "brown" in the sun.
4. Non-white people can be pale, or "white-faced". Obviously it does not mean literally "white" - nor would it mean so if it were about a white person.
5. Non-white people can blush, or look 'pink'.

Why is it that when Hermione's face is described as "brown" everyone here says "Oh, if she were a brown person, there would be no need to mention this", but when it's described as "white", they say "Ah-hah! She *is* white!"?

If anything, Rowling has confirmed that The Cursed Child is canon, so this is a confirmation that Hermione being black is canon. Personally, I don't consider The Cursed Child to be canon (for completely different reasons), so I don't think Hermione is "canonically" black.

To be honest, I would guess Rowling imagined Hermione to be white, like herself, but just thought it was not important. But I also find it mind boggling that everyone glosses over the fact Harry has *blue eyes* in the films, which is directly contradictory to the canon, but can't get over the fact Hermione is black in the play, which is not.

One last point, which is perhaps not relevant: the options are not "white, black or mixed-race". There are "races" which are neither white nor black.

Comment: This appears to be an extended comment on the answers above (and more than a little rant-y) rather than an answer in its own right.

Comment: @Valorum I disagree, it is the only answer that states that the answer is simply "No", which I think is important. Everything else is just about mentioning irrelevant things. I don't see how it matters if it's "rant-y".

Comment: I think it is important to point out that none of the other answers are based on canon, except a few that are based on irrelevant things (like her face being described as brown or being described as white, both of which somehow lead people to conclude that she is white). I also mentioned that the only "canon" info we have is, at best, that she is black, since The Cursed Child is considered canon by the author.

Comment: So sorry, but I really don't see how this merits a downvote.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't seem to be an answer in its own right, but rather a denial without foundation of the (better) answers above it.

Comment: @Valorum I honestly don't understand what you're saying. I'd understand it if you said you downvoted because you think my answer is wrong, but it's odd to me that you say it is not an answer in its own right. It is the only answer that says the answer is simply No. It is thus definitely an answer and definitely distinct from the rest. For context, I explained why I disagree with the other answers.

Comment: Well, for starters several of the illustrations are by JKR herself. They might not meet your definition of canon, but they can't just be brushed aside. Similarly, non-white people can indeed go darker in the sun, but an English author simply wouldn't describe them as such, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum And again I'd understand if you said my answer is wrong, not that it's not an answer. This explanation for downvoting just doesn't make sense to me. Nevermind.

Comment: "Similarly, non-white people can indeed go darker in the sun, but an English author simply wouldn't describe them as such" - there's the rub. This is your opinion and you don't like the fact I disagree with you (despite the fact the author herself does).

Comment: If from the start you'd have said you're downvoting me because my answer is wrong/makes no sense I'd believed that. But saying that you did because it is not an answer in its own right, and then explaining this odd statement by explaining why it's a wrong answer... and how "you can't brush aside" the things you yourself said... Come on.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that you praised (and certainly didn't criticize) an answer that says Hermione might be a freaking Panda. So I don't think you downvoted me because "This is not an answer in its own right" (a statement which you completely failed to justify), not because you strongly disagree with it (or you'd say so from the start), I think you did it just because I strongly disagreed with your answer, and because I was "rant-y". Sheesh.

Comment: @Wade The attitude you have about it here is making it hard to feel sympathetic about your ‘hate’ for the site.

Comment: @suchiuomizu Perhaps you are right. I took it a little too much to heart. It is just that something about the way most commentators here seem to think you can only describe white people as white with fear, pink from embarrassment or brown due to tan made me upset. Also, I genuinely didn't understand the reasons for the downvoting, unless it is directly because my answer was too angry...