# What does Hermione see in the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

I had a question while looking at Harry Potter things. What does Hermione see in the Mirror of Erised? There are some videos, and you could guess, but I want to know if J.K. Rowling has said what Hermione sees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When did J.K. Rowling decide to make Ron and Hermione a couple?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216875/when-did-j-k-rowling-decide-to-make-ron-and-hermione-a-couple) - the answer contains a JKR quote about _"Hermione would also see herself closely entwined...with...another...person..."_ and this question is among the first results when searching this site for `hermione erised`. Hence why I think it's a duplicate, it falling into the "can be answered with satisfaction by reading the answers to another question"

Comment: @Jenayah - It answers the question, but I wouldn't say that it was a natural dupe

Comment: @Valorum trueish, but all HP questions are dupes at this point. I'm of the opinion that having somebody copy-paste the bit of the earlier answer as a new one doesn't make the site any better and will encourage asking for random trivia without showing any attempt first, but I guess at the end of the day that's HP questions for you.

Comment: @Jenayah - I've added the *full* quote to an answer below. The danger with duping off partial quotes is that they sometimes lack context.

Comment: I have voted to leave open. If we closed as duplicates based on quotes appearing in an answer practically all questions that are answered by JKR tweets would be a duplicate of this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121097/is-there-a-complete-list-of-jk-rowlings-harry-potter-tweets

Comment: @Martha when plainly searching the site for the two main keywords brings the answer, and someone just has to follow a link, I see no point in separating the stuff into a question of its own. I'm perfectly fine with others thinking otherwise though.

Comment: Since it's not getting closed as a dupe, you don't need to defend the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hermione's desires are mixed. At the end of book 5, her desire would be to see Ron, Harry and herself healthy and well after having defeated Voldemort as well as seeing herself in a romantic clinch with *someone* (that we now know to be Ron).

> **Nina:** ***I just wanted to know what Hermione would see if she looked into the Mirror of Erised?***
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *Well, (big grin from Jo, crowd laughs and applauds) at the moment, as you know, Harry, Ron, and Hermione have just finished their penultimate year at Hogwarts and Hermione and Ron have told Harry that they're going to go with him wherever he goes next. So **at the moment I think that Hermione would see most likely the three of them alive and unscathed and Voldemort finished.***
>
> *But **I think that Hermione would also see herself closely entwined... with... another... person** (crowd roars and applauds loudly). **I think you can probably guess who.** Thank you, very good question. I've never been asked that before. Now we have another.*
>
> <sub><sup>[An Evening with Harry, Carrie and Garp:
> Readings and questions #1, August 1, 2006](http://An%20Evening%20with%20Harry,%20Carrie%20and%20Garp:%20Readings%20and%20questions%20#1,%20August%201,%202006)</sup></sub>